# Combination of PyCharm and ipython fails to import qt5 or Qt5Agg

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, ipython, pycharm

I have installed elementary os and Pycharm and the whole python stack via `conda`, and now have troubles starting interactive matplotlib in the `ipython` sesssion.

Here's pycharm's ipython session:

```
/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/bin/python3.5 /opt/pycharm-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 41070 33134
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
PyDev console: using IPython 5.0.0

import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))

Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
```

And here is what happens if I try to import `pyplot`:

```
In[4]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 502, in enable_gui
    gui_hook = guis[gui]
KeyError: 'qt5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 123, in enable_gui
    return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 508, in enable_gui
    raise ValueError(e)
ValueError: Invalid GUI request 'qt5', valid ones are:dict_keys(['gtk3', 'wx', 'qt', 'osx', 'pyglet', 'glut', 'tk', 'gtk', 'none', 'qt4'])

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2869, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-eff513f636fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

- This problem only happens when `ipython` is installed. **When I don't select ipython, however, I only get an irresponsive black screen when I `plt.figure()`**.
- This problem does not happen when I start `ipython` manually from the terminal (outside of pycharm). Also, if I do `matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')` before importing `pyplot`, the error persists in pycharm, but does not appear in the ipython console in my terminal.
- Installing on a new conda environment following `conda create -n test python=3.5 ; conda install ipython matplotlib scipy -n test` and loading the new environment in pycharm did not help
- Reinstalling pycharm 2.3 or Invalidate Caches + Restart did not help
- Installing pycharm educational 3.0 did not help

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 8):

Pycharm appears to not fully support `qt5`, the issue is [open](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20981). Downgrading it is the fastest workaround.

With conda the following will perform a downgrade to the last stable version:

```
conda install pyqt=4.11.4
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can configure your matplotlibrc as reported in http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

on linux the file should go in .config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc

just set:

```
backend      : qt4Agg
```

this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py` change the default value of `gui` from `None` to `qt4` :

```
 # In the PyDev Console, GUI control is done via hookable XML-RPC server
@staticmethod
def enable_gui(gui=qt4, app=None):
    """Switch amongst GUI input hooks by name.
    """
```